# Need to convert all columns in a row with unique values infront?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have data frame where i need to convert all the column in a row with their unique values

```
A       B       C
1       2       2
1       2       3
5       2       9
```

Desired output

```
X1   V1
A    1
A    5
B    2
C    2
C    3
C    9
```

I can get unique values by unique() function but don't know how I get desired output in pandas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `melt` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.melt(var_name='X1', value_name='V1').drop_duplicates()
```

Output:

```
  X1  V1
0  A   1
2  A   5
3  B   2
6  C   2
7  C   3
8  C   9
```

P.S. And you can add `.reset_index(drop=True)` if you want to have sequential integers for index